# Dojo Deferred chaining

Tags: dojo, deferred

I am having trouble wrapping my head around how to make a Dojo Deferred work for the following scenario. Basically I have a function that is supposed to loop through a number of items and process each item separately in a deferred manner. It does the processing of each item in a separate method that returns a Deferred when it is done. I want to be able to execute the loop to go off and process each item and report back a success or failure when it is done. Here is what I got so far as a test sample:

http://jsfiddle.net/Ayyoudy/mgv6Y/12/

What am I doing wrong? I am expecting the output numbers to be in sequence but they are not.

I also want to be able to detect if there is an error processing one of the items and if so, not to process the rest.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. I have resolve that the output number should be in sequence. http://jsfiddle.net/granjoy/mgv6Y/17/
   There're couple of issues in your code

   - loopping function should use closure to hold the variable.
   - You should use the validate returned Deferred now the process Deferred
2. Given that process() function will finished immediately, so the log "done processing everything!" will be first output.

Edit:

I have learn from the question. Thanks, the author gives another good solution. http://jsfiddle.net/Ayyoudy/mgv6Y/14

Comment: Thank you for that. I just don't see how the result is ordered because the log is all over the place. I do like your idea of closure functions. I expect the output to say:
done 1, done 2, done 3, done 4, done 5, done 6, done 7, done 8, done 8, done 9, done 10, done processing everything

Comment: It's all about the Math.random() in function validate(). Please refer to if you like http://jsfiddle.net/granjoy/mgv6Y/17/. If you think it helps, please vote. :P

Comment: Thanks, I'll accept the answer but I think you are forcing the ordering by setting the timeout to be higher for all subsequent items when you're multiplying it by the id. So of course the earlier items will resolve first :)... I actually intentionally had the randomness timeout factor in there because I don't know how long each will resolve. Here is what I did and I think it works: http://jsfiddle.net/Ayyoudy/mgv6Y/14/

again, thanks for the help!!!

Comment: You could also take advantage of dojo.DeferredList to make the final synchronization point... see http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/dojo/DeferredList